# Get reference to current view controller Xcode UI Unit test

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, user-interface

I've watched the WWDC video on Xcode UI Unit testing and am trying to incorporate it into my app.

In a particular scene of my app, when the user taps a button, the app runs some logic. Based upon the result of this logic, the VC is either dismissed or stays. I'd like to run a UI test to ensure that the VC is dismissed or stays based upon known inputs. How do I get a reference to the currently displaying view controller though the XCElementQuery?

Comment: Have you by any chance figured this out yet? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am so far haven't figured this out.